# How can i fix the code so the progressBar1 will show the percentages from 0% to 100%?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In jumps of 1 steps 1%...2%...3%...4%...5%
What happen now is few things. First the code is working fine the backgroundworker is start calling the Convert method and it's getting to the backgroundworker completed event. Not sure if the completed event is needed at all.

You can see in button1 click event i set this labels first time with the number of frames. and progressBar1 maximum.

The problems are:

1. On label12 i see 290 as maximum of progressBar1 but in fact there are only 280 frames, On label14 it's showing that there are 280 frames count.
2. In the end of the process i see on label12 the value 281 but there are 280 frames why it's counting to 281 ?
3. The percentages on label11 not moving at all it's staying on 0% all the time.

On form1 load event:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RichTextBox1.Visible = false;
            ProgressBar1.Value = 0;       
            Button5.Enabled = false;      
            KB = 1024;
            MB = KB * 1024;                
            GB = MB * 1024;
            psiProcInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            prcFFMPEG = new Process();
        }
```

On button1 click event

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OFD = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (OFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                mFile = new MediaFile(OFD.FileName);
                InputFile = OFD.FileName;
                pathResult = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(OFD.FileName);
                Label3.Text = "Name: " + pathResult;
                if (mFile.FileSize > 1070000000)
                {
                    Label4.Text = "FileSize: " + String.Format("{0:0.00}", mFile.FileSize / KB / MB) + " GB.";
                }
                else
                {
                    Label4.Text = "FileSize: " + String.Format("{0:0.00}", mFile.FileSize / MB) + " MB.";
                }
                Label5.Text = "Duration: " + mFile.Video[0].DurationString;
                Label6.Text = "Format: " + mFile.Video[0].Format;
                Label7.Text = "Codec: " + mFile.Video[0].CodecID;
                Label8.Text = "Resolution: " + mFile.Video[0].FrameSize;
                Label9.Text = "Framerate: " + mFile.Video[0].FrameRate;
                Label14.Text = "NumberOfFrames: " + mFile.Video[0].SourceFile.FrameCount.ToString();
                Label15.Text = "VideoStreams: " + mFile.Video[0].StreamType + " " + mFile.Video[0].StreamIndex;
                FCount = int.Parse(mFile.Video[0].SourceFile.FrameCount.ToString());

                ProgressBar1.Maximum = FCount + 10;
                Label12.Text = ProgressBar1.Maximum.ToString();
            }
        }
```

The Convert method that in there i'm doing the calculations of the reporting the progress to the progressBar1 and labels.

```
private void Convert()
        {
            Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
            if (ComboBox1.SelectedIndex == 3)
            {
                strFFCMD = " -i \"" + InputFile + "\" \"" + OutputFile + "\"";
            }

            if (ComboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2) 
            {
                strFFCMD = " -i " + (char)34 + InputFile + (char)34 +
                " -c:v libx264 -s 1280x720 -pix_fmt yuv420p -qp 20 -profile high444-c:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -ac 2 " + OutputFile;
            }
            psiProcInfo.FileName = exepath;
            psiProcInfo.Arguments = strFFCMD;        
            psiProcInfo.UseShellExecute = false;      
            psiProcInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;    
            psiProcInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;             
            psiProcInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;         
            psiProcInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;                 
            prcFFMPEG.StartInfo = psiProcInfo;           
            prcFFMPEG.Start();
            ffReader = prcFFMPEG.StandardError;

            do
            {
                if (Bgw1.CancellationPending)
                {
                    return;
                }
                Button5.Enabled = true;
                Button3.Enabled = false;
                strFFOUT = ffReader.ReadLine();
                //Show each read line in the richtextbox
                RichTextBox1.Text = strFFOUT;
                if (strFFOUT != null)
                {
                    if (strFFOUT.Contains("frame="))
                    {
                        currentFramestr = strFFOUT.Substring(7, 6).Trim();
                        Regex rx = new Regex(@"^\d+");
                        Match m = rx.Match(currentFramestr);
                        if (m.Success)
                        {
                            currentFrameInt = System.Convert.ToInt32(m.Value);
                        }
                    }
                }

                string percentage = System.Convert.ToInt32((ProgressBar1.Value / ProgressBar1.Maximum * 100)).ToString() + "%";
                ProgressBar1.Maximum = FCount + 1000;
                ProgressBar1.Value = (currentFrameInt);
                Label12.Text = "Current Encoded Frame: " + currentFrameInt;
                Label11.Text = percentage;
            } while (!(prcFFMPEG.HasExited || string.IsNullOrEmpty(strFFOUT)));
        }
```

Then the backgroundworker dowork event:

```
private void Bgw1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Convert();
        }
```

I'm not using the backgroundworker progresschanged event and completed event.
Just used a break point on the completed event and saw it's getting there in the end.

Now some values i get using a break point inside the Convert method. I added a breakpoint on the line:

```
if (m.Success)
                        {
                            currentFrameInt = System.Convert.ToInt32(m.Value);
                        }
```

First time the value in m.Value is "9"
Then "17"

And it finish stop getting to the completed event on "17"
Now i'm not using a break point at all.

The first value is "9" in the end it's 281 i could see that near the end it jumped from 269 to 281.

This is a screenshot of the form1 when the process completed using a break point:

[image: Form1 with break point use]

Current Encoded Frame : 17 thats Label12

NumberOfFrames: 280 thats Label14

The 0% on the right of the progressBar1 that never change and stay on 0% all the time is Label11

And this is a screenshot of form1 without using any break point:

[image: Form1 without using any break points]

In top of form1:

```
private Process prcFFMPEG;
private ProcessStartInfo psiProcInfo;
private string strFFCMD;
private StreamReader ffReader;
private string strFFOUT;
private string currentFramestr;
private int currentFrameInt;
```

Comment: Issue 1. looks as though it is caused by you setting `ProgressBar1.Maximum = FCount + 10;`. I presume `FCount` is 280, well you are adding 10 to that value and assigning it to the progress bar, which you then read back for `Label12`.

Comment: Right FCount is 280. But removing the + 10 didn't change much.

Comment: Thats the only instance that you set `Label12` to a single value. If that isn't it and `ProgressBar.Maximum` is 280 after setting it to `FCount` then I'm at a loss. Is it possible it's being set elsewhere that you haven't posted? I'd also look into the [ProgressChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of the `BackgroundWorker` to report your progress instead of doing it all in the `Convert` method.

Comment: Stephen what i did is removed the + 10 from the progressbar maximum and then inside the Convert method removed the + 1000 again from the progressbar maximum. So inside the button1 click event it's now: ProgressBar1.Maximum = FCount; and in the Convert method it's: ProgressBar1.Maximum = FCount + 1;

Comment: Now the progressBar1 is getting to 100% the problem now is that the percentages and also the frames jump in 9's sometimes in 8's i mean the first frame is 9 then 16 then 24...same the percentages it's not moving by 1...2...3...4...5 but that maybe the way it's working maybe it should be like that i'm not sure.

Comment: The problem that i think is important and yet i can't fix it is that now the progressBar getting to 100% and in the end i see on Current Encoded Frame: label12 i see in the end of the process the number: 281 but there are only 280 frames. At least thats what the FrameCount give: Label14.Text = "NumberOfFrames: " + mFile.Video[0].SourceFile.FrameCount.ToString(); so i'm not sure why if there are 280 frames in the end it's showing 281.

Comment: On your issue with the jumping, I'd expect that this has to do with the UI thread not continually updating, otherwise you'd spend the majority of your process simply updating a progress bar. If you write out the `percentage` value using `Debug.WriteLine(...)` I'd expect you'll see it goes 1, 2, 3...99, 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As @Stephen Ross mentioned you are setting `label12 = ProgressBar1.Maximum = FCount + 10 = Framecount + 10 = 280 + 10 = 290`
2. You are getting the value of `label12` from `ffReader = prcFFMPEG.StandardError;`. It is hard to say anything without knowing this process `prcFFMPEG`. But I guess it is returning the error value `frame=281` at the end. But there could also be something wrong with your `Trim` or your `RegEx`.
3. To solve Issue 3, you should cast your `ProgressBar1` values to `double`:
   `label11 = percentage = ... = ((double)ProgressBar1.Value / (double)ProgressBar1.Maximum * 100.0)`

Comment: So far i solved only issue 3. I didn't understand what to do with issue 1 yet. And in issue 2 add to my question ffReader is StreamReader and prcFFMPEG is type Process.